# How to resize images on sequential functions?

Tags: command-line, images, conversion, optimization

I am trying to:

- change the format of my images,
- then resize their height and width of 40%
- then optimize their quality to 35% max of the source and the total size of the image to 35% of the origin.

Here my code:

```
find . -name '*.png' -exec mogrify -format jpg {} + &&
find . -name '*.{jpeg,jpg}' -exec convert -resize 40% _resized.jpg {} + &&
find ./*.{jpeg,jpg} -exec jpegoptim   -m 35%  --size=35% {} \;
```

The resizing -line 2- seems to fail. When I am looking at image property I am getting the same image dimensions.

I expect that the new image:
  - is resized
  - have the original name + the "resized" word at  the end of the name

Comment: AFAIK, the patterns passed to `find` should be simple shell globs (which don't include brace expansions like `{jpeg,jpg}`)

Comment: @steeldriver thanks for your answer, can you provide an example illustrating what you are thinking about please?

Comment: TBH I'm reluctant to propose an answer since I'm not too familiar with how ImageMagick's `convert` handles the conversion / renaming of multiple files (and I don't want to suggest something that might end up being destructive)

Comment: @steeldriver I understand thanks

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with your second command is that `find` doesn't understand the brace expansion `{jpeg,jpg}` so will treat it as a literal string. A second problem is that, by using the `{} +` argument form, you are trying to pass multiple files to a single invocation of `convert`.

**Note: remove the `echo` only once you are happy that the command(s) below are doing the right thing.**

Probably what you want is something like:

```
find . \( -name '*.jpeg' -o -name '*.jpg' \) -exec sh -c '
  for f; do 
    ext="${f##*.}"; echo convert -resize 40% "$f" "${f%.*}_resized.$ext"
  done
' find-sh {} +
```

The `\(` ... `\)` parentheses are necessary because `-exec` binds more strongly than `-o`. Without them, files matching `-name '*.jpeg'` will be found but not converted.

If you're not so picky about the output file name, you could simplify the above to

```
find . \( -name '*.jpeg' -o -name '*.jpg' \) -exec sh -c '
  for f; do 
    echo convert -resize 40% "$f" "${f%.*}_resized.jpg"
  done
' find-sh {} +
```

(which will produce output files with the `.jpg` extension even if the original file had `.jpeg`) or even

```
find . \( -name '*.jpeg' -o -name '*.jpg' \) -exec sh -c '
  for f; do 
    echo convert -resize 40% "$f" "${f}_resized.jpg"
  done
' find-sh {} +
```

(which will produce output files like `foo.jpeg_resized.jpg`).

If you don't care about efficiency either, you could make one shell invocation for each file found and do away with the shell loop:

```
find . \( -name '*.jpeg' -o -name '*.jpg' \) -exec sh -c '
  echo convert -resize 40% "$1" "${1}_resized.jpg"
' find-sh {} \;
```

---

Note that in your third command

```
find ./*.{jpeg,jpg} -exec jpegoptim   -m 35%  --size=35% {} \;
```

your *shell* will likely expand the unquoted `{jpeg,jpg}` but that's not what you want either - again, that should likely be

```
find . \( -name '*.jpeg' -o -name '*.jpg' \) -exec jpegoptim -m 35%  --size=35% {} \;
```

Comment: It's not that `-exec` binds more strongly, it's that `-a` (implied when `-o` is not used between two predicates) has higher precedence than `-o`, like `&&` has higher precedence than `||` in many languages (`a -o b c` is short for `a -o b -a c` which is `a OR (b AND c)`, not `(a OR b) AND c`)

Answer (score -1):

Tell me if this helps you, if I understand you correctly:

```
find . -name "*.jpeg" -o -name "*.jpg" -exec bash -c 'convert -resize 40% "{}" "{}"_resized.jpg' \;
```

Comment: `-a` has precedence over `-o` so the `-exec` would only apply to `.jpg` files.

Comment: Embedding the `{}` in the code argument to `bash` (or any language interpreter for that matters), beside being unportable is very bad practice as it introduces command injection vulnerabilities.